# CAll to function does not work inside directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular Object Table (https://github.com/ekokotov/object-table) to list some basic info from my web api service. Works great.

On a couple of my outputs, i have added a Delete button, so the user can delete the entry.
I have a delete function, in my controller, that works. Have tested it.
What i cannot seem to get to work, is having the button inside the directive.

My code looks like this:

```
<table object-table
                                   from-url="http://myapi.com"
                                   data="myVar"
                                   display="100"
                                   headers="Header 1, Header 2"
                                   fields="Field1, field2"
                                   sorting="true">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Header 1</th>
                                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <td>Actions</td>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{::item.field2}}</td>
                                    <td>{{::item.field2}}</td>
                                    <td><button ng-click="ctrl.delete(item.id)">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

The delete function, never gets called.
If i, however, place the excat same button outside the `<table object-table>` like so;

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.delete('hardcodedId')">Delete</button>
<table object-table>...</table>
```

Then it works. So something inside the directive overwrites my ctrl = vm, that ui-router uses, i am thinking.

My controller looks something like this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope, $http, $window) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.delete = function (id) {
        }

        return vm;
    });
```

Comment: What type of scope are you using for the directive? Isolate, inherited, or none? It would be helpful to see your directive code since that is where you are having a problem.

Comment: The directive, i am refering to, is the Angular Object Table (https://github.com/ekokotov/object-table) It is not a directive of my own, thats the problem. Sorry for the confussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Angular Object Table source code](https://github.com/ekokotov/object-table/blob/master/src/js/directive.js#L10), it uses isolate scope. That is the reason functions inside the directive are not accessing functions outside.

The table data is available inside the directive scope as `ctrl.data` which can be edited by either directives or controllers inside the `object-table`.

Comment: So in other words, i cannot call my function as in my example above?

Comment: That is correct. Directives like `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` use inherited scope and functions inside can access functions in parent scopes. However, `object-table` uses isolate scope. My recommendation is put common functions in a service.

Comment: It's not that common of a function - its a function to delete a entry :-). how could a service, and a call to it, look?